# PostgreSQL: Filter and Aggregate on JSONB Array type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Consider the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE keys
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    key_value jsonb[] NOT NULL DEFAULT ARRAY[]::jsonb[],
)
```

The table now contains the following values:

```
id | key_value
---|-----------
1  | {"{\"a\": \1\", \"b\": \"2\", \"c\": \"3\"}","{\"a\": \"4\", \"b\": \"5\", \"c\": \"6\"}","{\"a\": \"7\", \"b\": \"8\", \"c\": \"9\"}"} |
```

How do I:

1. Select all rows where value of `b` is NOT 2? I tried using the @> operator,
2. For the returned rows, for each key_value object, return c - a

My confusion stems from the fact that all methods dealing with JSONB in postgres seem to accept JSON or JSONB but none seem to work with JSONB[]. Not sure what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSONB[] is an array type that has JSONB items in it and you need to use ARRAY functions/operators to fetch the items out of it. Why not store as just JSONB?

Comment: Unfortunately its an existing system with several gigabyte of data already present.

Comment: Then you are going to look at this [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html)

Comment: Yeah, I kind of got it to work using unnest..just wondering if there is better way?

Comment: Not that I know of, you have nested types.  It would have been different if they had been stored as an actual JSON array of JSON objects. What you have is a Postgres ARRAY of JSON objects. This means you have to peel them apart using the appropriate type operators/functions for each layer.

Comment: Do you want the rows where one of the `b` is not 2, or where all of the `b` are not 2?

Comment: "*My confusion stems from the fact that all methods dealing with JSONB in postgres seem to accept JSON or JSONB but none seem to work with JSONB[]*" - that should tell you something ;) Converting it from `jsonb[]` to `jsonb` will be easier in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be better than doing this with `unnest` and normal relational operations?

`array` types and `json` are abominations in the face of the perfection that is relational sets.  The first rule of holes is that when you find yourself in one, stop digging and climb out of the hole.

```
with unwind as (
  select id, unnest(key_value) as kvjson
    from keys
)
select id, (kvjson->>'c')::int - (kvjson->>'a')::int as difference
  from unwind
 where kvjson->>'b' != '2';
```